# How to bridge/enable (ICS) to a 3G modem?

Tags: wireless-networking, modem, broadband, bridging

I have two 3G modems, I want the first modem to bridge it with an Ethernet or wifi connection on my friend's computer which has a high speed 
and unlimited DSL internet.

I do it in order to share the computer’s internet with my second modem which I would use it on my own computer for browsing at remote distance. 
Both of the modems are connected to same 3G operator… there is no internet bundle activated on any of the modems but can be connected to the network 
with enabled LAN sharing capabilities (Both modems can communicate and ping each other).

Now I need help, how I can bridge the first modem with Ethernet/WiFi so I use my friend's computer internet on my own computer at remote distance *(Over 3G LAN)*.

In other words, how I can share my friend's computer internet to the modem’s network in order I benefit from unlimited browsing in my own PC using second modem?

I think it is possible, but don’t know how.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to configure the bridged 3G modem to act as an APN and then configure your mobile 3G modem to use this APN. I don't even know if it's possible to just set up a private APN or if the mobile carriers have to enable your APN somehow. But it almost definitely means having a DNS hostname pointing to the (probably dynamic) IP address of the bridged modem.

Normally, when you connect the mobile modem to the internet, you use your carriers APN, in my case it's "data.tre.dk", which means the modem uses this as the internet gateway. 
In that case, all traffic is routed through this and via the regular old internet, and that pretty much defeats the purpose of connecting through your friends DSL.

In any case, I guess your speed will be limited by the base station your mobile modem is connected to, and not the backbone of the carrier. And the data transferred to your private APN will probably still count in your data usage limit (not sure though).

I would Google "3g private apn" if I was trying to do this. :-)

Comment: But the question is here  that how to bridge Ethernet with the broadband 3G modem?